# Configuring SSL on Jetty 9 Cannot find 'keyStore'

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

I am running a maven jetty plugin, I'd like to have an https on whenever I access the url

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
                <configuration>
                    <httpConnector impl="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">
                        <port>8081</port>
                        <keyStore>${project.build.directory}/jetty-ssl.keystore</keyStore>
                        <password>jetty6</password>
                        <keyPassword>jetty6</keyPassword>
                    </httpConnector>
                    <stopKey></stopKey>
                    <stopPort></stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

However when I run mvn:jetty:run I get this error, how do I configure SSL on jetty?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.3.v20140905:run (default-cli) on project brightworks-admin-app-web: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.3.v20140905:run for parameter keyStore: Cannot find 'keyStore' in class org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.MavenServerConnector -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#maven-config-https It's not possible to configure it in pom.xml anymore (in Jetty 9 and upwards).

Comment: Also `org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector` doesn't exist in Jetty 9 and upwards.